# Making table cells same row and make it look like buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code below that alerts the value of the cell whenever the user clicks on the row. The problem is that i want try to make the cells look like button and put them on the same roll i'm not really too sure if this is possible to accomplish. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```js
var obj2 = {};

var key3 = "Cars";
obj2[key3] = ['Toyota', 'Audi', 'Mercedes', 'Ferrari', 'Jeep', 'Honda', 'Nissan', 'Lamborghini'];
var myArray3 = [];
myArray3.push(obj2);

var bodyString = '';
var headString = '';
$.each(obj2[key3], function(index) {
  bodyString += ('<tr><td>' + obj2[key3][index] + '</td></tr>');
});
headString += ('<tr><th>' + 'Cars' + '</th></tr>');
$('.carsclass tbody').html(bodyString);
$('.carsclass thead').html(headString);


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#carsid td").click(function() {
    getval(this);
  });
});

function getval(cel) {
  alert(cel.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
  .class { 
  font-family: Open Sans; 
  }
  .center{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center
  }
  .skillsTable th{
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  }
  table{
  float: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:70%
  }
  td {
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 11px;
  font-size: 15px;
  }
  th {
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  div{
  margin-bottom:50px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="center">
    <table id="carsid" class="carsclass skillsTable class">
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is what im trying to accomplish.

[image: This is what i'm trying to accomplish.]

Comment: You must do it in table or not??

Comment: Do you have to use table element? Are you allowed to use flexbox?

Comment: @DavidLiang As long as the function stays the same its alright

Comment: @Bobby: See my post below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed some script and CSS to achieve your desired output but here you can't get an exact look like given image due to table

```js
var obj2 = {};

var key3 = "Cars";
obj2[key3] = ['Toyota', 'Audi', 'Mercedes', 'Ferrari', 'Jeep', 'Honda', 'Nissan', 'Lamborghini'];
var myArray3 = [];
myArray3.push(obj2);

var bodyString = '<tr>';
var headString = '';
$.each(obj2[key3], function(index) {
  bodyString += ('<td>' + obj2[key3][index] + '</td>');
});
bodyString += '</tr>';
headString += ('<tr><th colspan="' + obj2[key3].length + '">' + 'Cars' + '</th></tr>');
$('.carsclass tbody').html(bodyString);
$('.carsclass thead').html(headString);


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#carsid td").click(function() {
    getval(this);
  });
});

function getval(cel) {
  alert(cel.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}


table {
  float: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 70%
}

td {
  border: 0;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  padding-left: 11px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #007bff;
}

th {
  font-weight: normal;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="center">
    <table id="carsid" class="carsclass skillsTable class">
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh yeah thanks so much but is there any way to put a threshold like only 5 cells a row?

Comment: If you want a fixed number of elements in a row then you have to change some script by putting counter etc

Answer (score 3):

use blow code

```
  td {
      border-width: 1px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      border-color:black;  
      padding: 10px;
      cursor:pointer;
      font-size: 15px;
      background-color: #9fc5e8;
    }

    th {
      font-weight: normal;
      border: 0;
      padding: 10px 0;
    }

    div {
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
```

here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/deepakvaishnav/gfr36c1d/9/

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what i'm looking for but is that anyway to put a threshold like only 5 cells will be in one row?

Answer (score 1):

use below css.

```
<style>
#carsid {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#carsid td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#carsid tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#carsid tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#carsid th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: it still looks just like a normal table

Comment: Im trying to achieve smth like the picture above

Comment: Oh sorry, couldn't see your pic due to add blocks. actually those are not cells i think, those are buttons.

Comment: doesn't have to be buttons just trying to make it look something like this

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach using `flex-box` instead of `table`.

#### HTML

```
<div id="cars-container"></div>
```

#### JavaScript with jQuery

```
let cars = [
    'Toyota',
    'Audi',
    'Mercedes',
    'Ferrari',
    'Jeep',
    'Honda',
    'Nissan',
    'Lamborghini',
    'Hyundai'
];

let $carsContainer = $('#cars-container');

// Empty the container first
$carsContainer.html('');

// Loop through the car collection
$.each(cars, function(index, car) {
    let $button = $('<button />', {
        text: car,
        value: car,
        click: function() {
            alert(this.value);
        }
    });
    $carsContainer.append($button);
});
```

#### CSS

```
#cars-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

#cars-container button {
    padding: .375rem 1.25rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid #aaa5a4;
    background-color: #9fc5e8;
    margin: .25rem;
}

#cars-container button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #8ab9e3;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/233802/

Now reading from one of the comments, if the user of OP wants only 5 cars in a row, you can easily add a style to the `button`:

```
#cars-container button {
    ...
    width: calc(100% / 5 - 2 * .25rem); <!-- Percentage - margin left - margin right -->
}
```

But I would highly **not** recommend to put a fixed width on the `button` element. That defeats the purpose of using `flex-box` - the flexibility and responsiveness it gives.

Instead, you can setup media breakpoints and do what works fine at that breakpoint (mobile-first approach). For example:

At extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px), I want the buttons to be vertically aligned. I can change the initial css flex-flow property to column instead of row.

```
#cars-container {
    ...
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    ...
}
```

[image]

Then on small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up), I might want only 2 items per row.

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    #cars-container {
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }

    #cars-container button {
       width: calc(100% / 2 - 2 * .25rem);
    }
}
```

[image]

On Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up), I might want only 3 items per row.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #cars-container {
        width: calc(100% / 3 - 2 * .25rem);
    }
}
```

[image]

You got the idea. You just need to change the **divisor** for the numbers of items you want per row.

Here is the working example with breakpoints: https://jsfiddle.net/rnvt689w/13/